# SSIS not writing file while executing from different user

Tags: ssis-2012

I have developed SSIS package to export data to excel file. below are the steps executed by the package
1.Send mail of starting package
2.Copy excel Template to Source folder ( This is Temporary file )
3. Retrieve data  (In this step we are retrieve data from 6-7 tables)
4.create folder structure  to export i.e First check folder for year and month if not exist dot create
5.Copy the source folder file (Step2) to above create folder.
The problem here is when I deploy and execute package through my account its run perfectly. But same package with same setting if I run through different account its not writing file ie. Its copies source file at the end. but in execution it shows its executed successfully at the start. [click for excution Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCamo.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, please check your account permission for the one you failed to run the package. The account to execute to package should have the full permission to read from database and also make sure that account could visit, read and write to windows directory.